# how does heroku route requests to the correct port?

Tags: node.js, heroku

After reading several Heroku NodeJS tutorials, I've learned that Heroku assigns a random port to your application via the "process.env.PORT" environment variable, and that the correct way to get your app to work both locally and on heroku is to set the port to be equal to

`process.env.PORT || 8000`

, where 8000 can be replaced by whatever port you want your app to run on when you are running on localhost.

Here's how it looks in my app ("server" being the http server, which is currently serving a static HTML file):

`server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000)`

When I run the app on heroku and check the logs, I'll see that process.env.PORT was assigned a port number... this previous deployment, it was 29074.

When I run the app locally, I connect via the url http://localhost:8000. If I don't include the port number, then the page doesn't load (page cannot be found).

Why, then, do I not have to specify the port 29074 in the URL when I connect to the page on heroku? I can visit the url https://limitless-brook-9339.herokuapp.com/ without specifying the port number and it loads fine. In fact, if I try to explicitly set the port in the URL to :29074, it says "This webpage is not available".

Comment: There is still a port number involved with each request. HTTP and HTTPS each just have defaults (`80` and `443`, respectively) that are used if another isn't specified (like the `8000` you're using locally). If the port number isn't already in use on your local machine, it's possible to use `.listen(80)` and visit `http://localhost/`.

Comment: From what I understand, 443 is being implicitly added to the the URL when I visit https://limitless-brook-9339.herokuapp.com (since it's HTTPS).  But when I check my heroku logs, `process.env.PORT` (and therefore, the argument being passed into `server.listen`) is equal to 29074. If the app is listening on 29074 when running on heroku, I have no idea how the request in my browser is being correctly routed if the port I'm providing is 443.

Comment: Heroku is likely using a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). This would listen on the default ports and direct requests to individual applications on an assigned "private" port (29074, in this case). It allows them at least the ability to host multiple applications on one server.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. So I'm guessing this means that my app on heroku cannot actually listen on multiple ports, since heroku will only assign me a single `process.env.PORT` and will automatically route all requests from 443 to this port?

Comment: Not really. You can make use both `80` and `443` publicly, though both will appear to your application as the assigned port after the proxy, but [Heroku restricts network access to dynos on any others.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#network-interfaces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind, Heroku probably is doing some routing behind the scenes. If a request comes in it doesn't necessarily hit your application (running Express, for example). It's most likely hitting something like nginx, which can do it's own internal routing based on the hostname.

The statement `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000)` is specifying the port - it's either the value of process.env.PORT (which is specified by setting PORT=80 (or PORT=443) on the command line) or using port 8000 as a default.